# How do I get the Index of the max value in a column so I can get a value from a different column but same row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, argmax

The output of the panda's data frame:

```
          Date   Time      Hi      Lo    Open   Close Volume
0   2021-12-10   4:00  174.80  174.56  174.73   174.8    953
1   2021-12-10   4:01  174.78  174.78  174.78  174.78    100
2   2021-12-10   4:02  174.90  174.75   174.8  174.75    627
3   2021-12-10   4:03  174.93  174.91  174.91  174.93    268
4   2021-12-10   4:04  174.92  174.92  174.92  174.92    300
```

Code below will get the highest high in the Hi column:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df[(df['Time'] >= "4:01") & (df['Time'] <= "4:04")]['Hi'].max()
```

From here onwards I'm trying to get the index of the row of where the max value in **Hi** is positioned.

Code Below Someone recommended:

```
df.loc[df[(df['Time'] >= "4:01") & (df['Time'] <= "4:04")]['Hi'].idxmax()]
```

But if I run the code it'll give me this output:

```
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype is the call back
```

**My desired output I want is:**

```
HOD Time is 4:03
```

Comment: You sample data and code work for me

Comment: Works for me as well, maybe upgrade your numpy/pandas?

Comment: Uninstalled both and installed them again and still getting the same problem @Quang